# Spark/Scala Error - printing out Confusion Matrix for Logistic Regression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic regression on a dataset and it seems like everything works but when I am about to print out the confusion matrix I get the error I am not sure how to deal with.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics
val predictionAndLabels = results.select($"prediction", $"label").as[(Double, Double)].rdd

val metrics = new MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)

println("Confusion matrix:")
println(metrics.confusionMatrix)
```

Log message:

```
root
 |-- ORDER_QUANTITY: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- IS_BOUGHT: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- CUSTOMER_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- SNAPSHOT_DAY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WEEK_DAY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEVICE_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- HIT_TIME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MARKETPLACE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ASIN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VEL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- GL_PRODUCT_GROUP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IS_FT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- INSTOCK_STATUS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PDD_WD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FT_DAYS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IN_STOCK_QUANTITY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ASIN_PRICE: double (nullable = true)
 |-- PRICE_GAP: double (nullable = true)
 |-- IS_DISCOUNT: string (nullable = true)

logRegDataAll: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [label: int, DEVICE_TYPE: string ... 10 more fields]
logRegData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [label: int, DEVICE_TYPE: string ... 10 more fields]
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{VectorAssembler, StringIndexer, VectorIndexer, OneHotEncoder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
DeviceTypeIndexer: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer = strIdx_703e2f28bf96
MarketplaceIndexer: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer = strIdx_4bd47e3e31c5
VelocityIndexer: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer = strIdx_744315e59c01
GLIndexer: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer = strIdx_30a9705e2305
FTIndexer: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer = strIdx_fb2e7ec8b38c
InStockIndexer: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer = strIdx_15ceee49c6a9
PDDIndexer: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer = strIdx_a3987fcecd10
InStockQtyIndexer: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer = strIdx_9c0bc369a617
IsDicountIndexer: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer = strIdx_cf2902b30b63
DeviceTypeEncoder: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder = oneHot_5560566be7cb
MarketplaceEncoder: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder = oneHot_d2c6ca94f073
VelocityEncoder: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder = oneHot_0f1f237e9700
GLEncoder: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder = oneHot_70baf14c780a
FTEncoder: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder = oneHot_bb3312ac9c1e
InStockEncoder: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder = oneHot_f273d6b316b6
PDDEncoder: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder = oneHot_a663d8560283
InStockQtyEncoder: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder = oneHot_8300bb250ef0
IsDiscountEncoder: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder = oneHot_f5eed05b0391
assembler: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler = vecAssembler_474029a89693
training: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [label: int, DEVICE_TYPE: string ... 10 more fields]
test: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [label: int, DEVICE_TYPE: string ... 10 more fields]
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
lr: org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression = logreg_cf2a6574a539
pipeline: org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline = pipeline_2be53eb735dc
model: org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel = pipeline_2be53eb735dc                
results: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [label: int, DEVICE_TYPE: string ... 32 more fields]
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics
predictionAndLabels: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Double, Double)] = MapPartitionsRDD[1413] at rdd at <console>:292
metrics: org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics = org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics@f92e2af
```

Error:

```
Confusion matrix:
16/12/28 15:15:43 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 771.0 (TID 1651)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (string) => double)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label: 4500.
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:166)
    ... 15 more
16/12/28 15:15:43 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 2 in stage 771.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/12/28 15:15:43 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 771.0 (TID 1649)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (string) => double)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label: 3583.
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:166)
    ... 15 more
16/12/28 15:15:43 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 771.0 (TID 1650)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (string) => double)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label: 8710.
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:166)
    ... 15 more
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 771.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 771.0 (TID 1651, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (string) => double)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label: 4500.
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:166)
    ... 15 more

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1873)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1886)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1899)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1913)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:912)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:911)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$collectAsMap$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:745)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$collectAsMap$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:744)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.collectAsMap(PairRDDFunctions.scala:744)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.tpByClass$lzycompute(MulticlassMetrics.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.tpByClass(MulticlassMetrics.scala:44)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.labels$lzycompute(MulticlassMetrics.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.labels(MulticlassMetrics.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.confusionMatrix(MulticlassMetrics.scala:68)
  ... 159 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (string) => double)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label: 4500.
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:170)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:166)
  ... 15 more
```

EDIT:

When I don't split my data into a training and test set, I don't have any errors. How can I avoid the "unseen label" error for a pipeline fitting?

Comment: You have an unseen label: `Unseen label: 4500.` The reason it shows up when you try to print is because everything up to that point is being lazily evaluated so the ML stuff doesn't actually happen until you try to print

Comment: @evan058 How can I see what label is unseen? What are possible causes of the error? I found this [link] (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8764) but not sure what it means

Comment: Based on the error message I think the unseen label is `4500`. I can't figure out why this would happen without digging through your data

Answer (score 0):

I avoided the error by setting the exception handling.

```
val DeviceTypeIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("DEVICE_TYPE").setOutputCol("DeviceTypeIndex").setHandleInvalid("skip")
```